# Watch in isolated scope with two way binding not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a variable in my main scope:

`scope.trigger`

and in my directive:

```
angular.module('modal').directive('nsModal', ['nsTools', function (Tools) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope:{
        trigger: "="
    },
    templateUrl: 'common/modal.html',
    controller: ['$scope', function (scope) {

        scope.isShown = false;

        scope.$watch(function () {
            return scope.trigger;
        }, function (n) {
            if (n == 'order-button') {
                scope.isShown = true;

            }
            else {
                scope.isShown = false;
            }
        });
        scope.clickClose = function ()
        {
            scope.currentTrigger = "";
        }
        scope.clickCancel = function ()
        {
            scope.currentTrigger = "";
            scope.isShown = false;
        }

        scope.clickYes = function ()
        {
            scope.currentTrigger = "";
            scope.isShown = false;
        }
    }]
}
}]);
```

I want to change the mainscope trigger parameter so I made two way binding. But with it the watch is not working.
the scope.trigger in the watch is always undefined;

when I remove the `scope` section the watch works fine but then changes arent saved in main scope

html:
in my index:
`<ns-modal />`
and modal code:

```
<div ng-show="isShown">
    <div >
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modalheader>
            <p >Message</p>
            <button ng-click="clickClose()"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <span>Identify customer ?</span>
            <div class="modalfooter">
                <button id="cancel" ng-click="clickCancel()">No</button>
                <button id="save" ng-click="clickYes()">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

thats all

Comment: Can you put how the directive in your html is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your html, the trigger attribute should be added:

```
<ns-modal trigger="trigger"/>
```

Note that trigger might be any variable (but you wrote that in the main scope it's called trigger).

This because when this is added:

```
scope:{
    trigger: "="
},
```

a new scope for the directive is created. Therefore you should specify every single variable passed to the directive with an attribute;

Answer (score 1):

You should use watch on variable `trigger` with deep watch `true`.

```
 scope.$watch('trigger', function (n) {
        if (n == 'order-button') {
            scope.isShown = true;

        }
        else {
            scope.isShown = false;
        }
    }, true);
```

**Update**

As i said in comment you html should have `trigger="someVariable"`

**Markup**

```
<ns-modal trigger="someVariable"></ns-modal>
```

Comment: Tried it and its never triggered. It didnt see any changes in trigger

Comment: @szpic could you add your html part please? on html it should be `trigger="someVariable"`

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you may want to use Angular's events rather than `$watch` - as it is much more expensive. (use `$scope.$broadcast & $scope.$on`).

Second, if you can also specify how you use the directive - that would help to understand the problem.